# Php file weight calculation

Tags: magento-1.9, php, shipping, shipping-methods, table-rates

In the Magento 1.9 in which file takes the weight calculation for shipping?
I'm used the table rates mehod to shipping

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to look into the `Mage_Shipping_Model_Shipping` class?